# Julia InexactError: Int64

Tags: dataframe, error-handling, julia

I am new to Julia. Got this InexactError . To mention that I have tried to convert to float beforehand and it did not work, maybe I am doing something wrong.

```
column = df[:, i]  
max = maximum(column)
min = minimum(column)
scaled_column = (column .- min)/max   # This is the error, I think
df[:, i] = scaled_column
```

```
julia> VERSION
v"1.4.2"
```

Comment: What's `i`? A more complete MWE would be really helpful here.

Comment: Could you try to put a complete example that reproduces the error, and paste the full error message? Also, I would not advise to use max and min as variable names, as there are julia functions with those names. Finally, I think you should also add a dot before the division operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hard to give a sure answer without a minimal working example of the problem, but in general an InexactError happens when you try to convert a value to an exact type (like integer types, but unlike floating-point types) in which the original value cannot be exactly represented. For example:

```
julia> convert(Int, 1.0)
1

julia> convert(Int, 1.5)
ERROR: InexactError: Int64(1.5)
```

Other programming languages arbitrarily chose some way of rounding here (often truncation but sometimes rounding to nearest). Julia doesn't guess and requires you to be explicit. If you want to round, truncate, take a ceiling, etc. you can:

```
julia> floor(Int, 1.5)
1

julia> round(Int, 1.5)
2

julia> ceil(Int, 1.5)
2
```

Back to your problem: you're not calling `convert` anywhere, so why are you getting a conversion error? There are various situations where Julia will automatically call convert for you, typically when you try to assign a value to a typed location. For example, if you have an array of `Int`s and you assign a floating point value into it, it will be converted automatically:

```
julia> v = [1, 2, 3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> v[2] = 4.0
4.0

julia> v
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 4
 3

julia> v[2] = 4.5
ERROR: InexactError: Int64(4.5)
```

So that's likely what's happening to you: you get non-integer values by doing `(column .- min)/max` and then you try to assign it into an integer location and you get the error.

Comment: Note that the `df[:, i]` column exists; an MWE could be `julia> using DataFrames;
df = DataFrame(a = rand(1:10, 10)); scaled_column = (df.a .- minimum(df.a)) / maximum(df.a); df[:, :a] = scaled_column`

Comment: I'm not familiar with recent DataFrames, I would have thought that `df[:, i] = values` would replace the `i`th column rather than assigning to it in-place but if that does assign into the existing column then yes, that would do it.

Comment: Yes in this case `df[!, i]` replaces the column, while `df[:, i]` replaces values in-place. For future reference the current indexing behaviour is documented [here](https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/lib/indexing/#setindex!-1).

Comment: `df[:, i]` works in-place. In base writing `matrix[:, i] = v` or `matrix[:] = v` does not reallocate the whole matrix and update the binding to `matrix` either. `:` is just a row selector in this case, just like eg. `axes(df, 1)` would be (so `df[axes(df, 1), i] = value` is equivalent). The `!` selector is introduced exactly because it is not used in Base so it can follow a different rule.

Comment: Also imagine `df` would be a view - it is clear then that `df[:, i] = v` should not be allowed to replace the column, but should work in place. Finally - if `df` were e.g. a `Dict` or a `NamedTuple` then you would write `df[i][:] = v` as an equivalent syntax and I assume it is natural to expect that in this case the operation is in-place.

Comment: @NilsGudat very useful comment, solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a side note you can use `transform!` to achieve what you want like this:

```
transform!(df, i => (x -> (x .- minimum(x)) ./ maximum(x)) => i)
```

and this operation will replace the column.